# Cleaning semi redundant text

Tags: python, text, fuzzy-search, redundancy, fuzzywuzzy

First a little background:
[Link to attachments](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Azy86VK8VRYnUyakZnMUlnXzg)

I have a lot of text generated by some voice-to-text application (I honestly do not know the name of the application since I do not have physical access, however I have access to the live output).
I am mining this data realtime and the output text looks like the first attachment, some parts are very clean, and some, well, very redundant.

I have now written a piece of software in Python that cleans up the text (Attachment two). The thing is, I can only do it on a lot of text at a time, eg. my backups which has hundreds of megabytes of pure text, when it comes in realtime, it gets hard to process only a few strings, since the semi-redundancy lasts 15-25 lines (as you can see in attachment 1).

The software works on the bigger files, and I am now trying to rewrite the code so it works with the live output.

But since I am a self taught programmer, I was wondering if anybody could share how their approach to doing the job would be.

My approach is (also see attachment two, however I am bad at commenting, so I do not know if you would get much out of it):

1. Open the file(plain text) and wait until 25 lines has been
   written to the file
2. read 25 lines into a list, lets call it MasterList
3. run clean-up functions (1-7) on MasterList (see below)
4. Print lines 10-14 to cleaned up file (first time it prints lines 0-14)
5. Push line 5-24 of MasterList to the beginning of MasterList, making them now have indices 0-19
6. Read 5 new lines to Masterlist or wait until 5 new lines are ready
7. Go back to #3

--> Note regarding #3: 
The cleanup functions do the following:
*Compare lines by the use of Fuzzy String Matching, fuzzywuzzy, and delete duplicate or semiduplicate lines

*Check if the first word in a sentence is the same as the last word in the previous sentence, and in that case delete the last word in the previous sentence
*Smaller stuff, to make the text look clean.

My questions is:
Would you go about it in a completely different way?
Maybe machine learning?
Another language may be better suited?
Any libraries or even software that already would do this?

If you do read my code, I am also eager to learn my mistakes, if you see some stupid thing I am doing, criticism (even harsh criticism if you feel like bashing me) is very welcome.

Thank you ever so much for your time.

Comment: I should have been clearer regarding:
Print lines 10-14 to cleaned up file (first time it prints lines 0-14)

This is done to ensure that the lines have been properly checked, and therefore even though 25 lines are checked for redundancy, I am actually only focusing on 5 lines at a time.
If i only read in 5 lines at a time and disposed of them afterwards, I would not check these lines against prior or subsequent lines.

Comment: My friend, this is not how we work on StackOverflow. Here, we answer specific questions about programming. Most people here are inclined to answer questions accompanied by small snippets of code that get to the heart of the problem that the questionner is having. You really should read the help file for this site before asking any more questions.

Comment: I am sorry. I will read the help file..

Comment: No need for apology! We often get questions like that.

Comment: Thanks.. Would you happen to know of a better place to ask this sort of thing? 
I am looking at StackExchange, FindNerd and CodeRanch, but I have never used any of these (or have i used StackOverflow), and well, I really want to find some opinions on how to grasp the problem, before jumping into it (again)..

Comment: You could try on https://meta.stackexchange.com/, for information about where to ask.